# Sync MySQL database and Quickbooks Database

Tags: mysql, data-synchronization

I use Quickbooks as an accounting software. I also have a MySQL database where I record data on orders, customers, inventory, employees and etc. Is there a way for me to sync the two databases? For example, I would like to enter order details on Quickbooks and would like that order details to be in my MySQL database as well. Can someone please advice?

Answer (score 1):

quickbooks have completely different database, its not SQL based 
For quick books Enterprise you should have SQL data optimizer and you should be able integrate with MySQL. QuickBooks pro and premium don't have that feature but there are third party applications that might do database optimization.